# How can I carry out a fit with errors on both axis with lmfit module in Python?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

```
import lmfit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def test_func(x, a, b):
   model = a* np.exp(-b*np.array(x))
   return model       



df = pd.read_excel("esti.xlsx", usecols=["altezza", "err_altezza", "Icorrente", "err_I"])
x_var = df["altezza"].tolist()
x_err = df["err_altezza"].tolist()
y_var = df["Icorrente"].tolist()
y_err = df["err_I"].tolist()

mod = lmfit.Model(test_func)
pars = lmfit.Parameters()
pars.add('a', value=200)
pars.add('b', value=0)
result = mod.fit(y_var, x=x_var, params=pars, weights=y_err)
```

Idk how to include the noise on the x-axis. Lmfit give me the opportunity only to add the errors on the y-axis with the command "weights=".
Do you know a way to work with noises on both axes using lmfit?

Answer (score 1):

`lmfit` does not directly support uncertainties in the independent variable.
Here's a long-winded explanation, then a suggested alternative:

Non-linear fitting problems don't necessarily have a single, well-defined "independent variable", but are thought of as a series of observations (say "y") that can be modelled, and seek to find a set of parameters for a model to match the data, most typically in the least-squares sense:

Find a set of values for parameters `p` in order to minimize

```
  Sum_i [(y_i - model(p, i))/eps_y_i]^2
```

where `i` is the index of the observation, `y_i` is the observation, `eps_y_i` its uncertainty, and `model` is the function that models the observation in terms of the parameters `p`.

There sort of is not an `x` (or at least not always a single, well-defined `x`) there.  Indeed, the fitting algorithms typically do not require an `x` value.  When they take one, it is only to help the model function calculate the observation.  So, you *could* pass in an `eps_x` array along with `x` to your model function, and calculate a weighted model to best describe the observation at index `i`, but that is left as an exercise for the reader ;).

Anyway, that is why uncertainties in `x` are typically not handled, and in fact,  None of the codes in `scipy. optimize` or `lmfit` handle uncertainties in `x`.

*Suggested Alternative:*

However: there is `scipy.odr` which is sort of oddly in a separate module and with a sort of unusual interface.  This ODR approach can include uncertainties in `x`.  So, that might be worth looking into.  ODR is not supported in `lmfit`. That would take some real effort, but might be doable if someone was so motivated.